# Golang exec process and to disown it

Tags: linux, go, fork, exec

I am trying to fork processes with my daemon, and trying to disown them in case of my daemon crashes. Regular `os/exec` is high-level, therefore I went for `syscall.ForkExec` and produced the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    cmd := "myproc"
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath(cmd)
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }
    fmt.Println(binary)

    os.Remove("/tmp/stdin")
    os.Remove("/tmp/stdout")
    os.Remove("/tmp/stderr")

    fstdin, err1 := os.Create("/tmp/stdin")
    fstdout, err2 := os.Create("/tmp/stdout")
    fstderr, err3 := os.Create("/tmp/stderr")
    if err1 != nil || err2 != nil || err3 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err1, err2, err3)
        panic("WOW")
    }

    argv := []string{"hi"}
    procAttr := syscall.ProcAttr{
        Dir:   "/tmp",
        Files: []uintptr{fstdin.Fd(), fstdout.Fd(), fstderr.Fd()},
        Env:   []string{"VAR1=ABC123"},
        Sys: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
            Foreground: false,
        },
    }

    pid, err := syscall.ForkExec(binary, argv, &procAttr)
    fmt.Println("Spawned proc", pid, err)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 100)
}
```

I have also made a simple application that sleeps and prints hello world and put it to path.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    while(1){
        printf("hello world");
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(300000);
        }
}
```

It works, however, the process is not send to background as I expected, my go process still owns the child. The `SysProcAttr` has the following values in Linux:

```
type SysProcAttr struct {
    Chroot      string         // Chroot.
    Credential  *Credential    // Credential.
    Ptrace      bool           // Enable tracing.
    Setsid      bool           // Create session.
    Setpgid     bool           // Set process group ID to Pgid, or, if Pgid == 0, to new pid.
    Setctty     bool           // Set controlling terminal to fd Ctty (only meaningful if Setsid is set)
    Noctty      bool           // Detach fd 0 from controlling terminal
    Ctty        int            // Controlling TTY fd
    Foreground  bool           // Place child's process group in foreground. (Implies Setpgid. Uses Ctty as fd of controlling TTY)
    Pgid        int            // Child's process group ID if Setpgid.
    Pdeathsig   Signal         // Signal that the process will get when its parent dies (Linux only)
    Cloneflags  uintptr        // Flags for clone calls (Linux only)
    UidMappings []SysProcIDMap // User ID mappings for user namespaces.
    GidMappings []SysProcIDMap // Group ID mappings for user namespaces.
    // GidMappingsEnableSetgroups enabling setgroups syscall.
    // If false, then setgroups syscall will be disabled for the child process.
    // This parameter is no-op if GidMappings == nil. Otherwise for unprivileged
    // users this should be set to false for mappings work.
    GidMappingsEnableSetgroups bool
}
```

I also tried the following but It caused an error:

```
Sys: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setsid:     true,
    Setctty:    true,
    Foreground: false,
 },

Spawned proc 0 inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Also the following:

```
Sys: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setsid:     true,
    Setctty:    true,
    Foreground: false,
    Noctty:     true,
    Setpgid:    true,
},

Spawned proc 0 operation not permitted (with root privilleges)
```

What am I doing/assuming wrong?
**Note:** Despite saying os/exec is high-level, I also tried the following, but it produced same results.

```
cs := exec.Command(binary)
cs.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setctty: true,
}
err := cs.Run()
fmt.Println(err)
```

Comment: Why do you think `exec.Cmd` is too high level? You have access to SysProcAttr from there too. Also, what do you mean by your process still owns the child? Is it in the same process group? Does it not get reassigned to PID 1 if the parent exits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A process forked with `Start()` will continue even after its parent dies.

```
func forker() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "3")
    cmd.Start()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Here the `sleep` process will happily live on for 3 seconds even if the parent process only lives for 2 seconds:

```
  $ forker &; while true; do ps -f; sleep 1; done

  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 71423 69892   0  3:01PM ttys003    0:00.07 forker
  501 71433 71432   0  3:01PM ttys003    0:00.00 sleep 3

  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 71423 69892   0  3:01PM ttys003    0:00.07 forker
  501 71433 71432   0  3:01PM ttys003    0:00.00 sleep 3

  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 71433     1   0  3:01PM ttys003    0:00.00 sleep 3
```

Notice how the parent process ID (`PPID`) of the `sleep` process became `1` when the parent process `71432` exited. This means that the `sleep` process has been orphaned.

Comment: The goal is to make 71432 equal 1 in the example above (immediately).

Comment: The question is phrased: "[...] in case of my daemon crashes [sic]". It's not necessary to forcily orphan the process immediately. With `Start()` it will be orphaned only when and if the parent dies.

Answer (score 2):

The [Start() method](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start) should give you what you're looking for. My script to append a simple text file after my sample Go program terminated continued to run:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./appender.sh")
    cmd.Start()
}
```

Comment: Note that if the command uses the stdin/stdout from the parent, if the parent terminates, the process might become a zombie.

Comment: @Anfernee I am executing a bash script from a Go program which inturn kills the parent go process at one stage . I had provided "stderr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()" before cmd.Start() and noticed that the child process running the script would also die after parent go process was killed . Once I removed the stderr line and executed the program , the child would continue its execution properly . Forgive me if I did not understand you but is this what you mentioned in the above comment . ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems good strategy for immediately disowning is spawning `os.Argv[0]` process (self-spawn), then spawning target process (with Setsid: true), and then exiting first spawned process. This way gradchild process immediately gets ppid 1. Optionally first spawned process can communicate pid of granchild via stdout to parent before it exits.

Answer (score 2):

Daemonization doesn't play well with go's goroutine scheduling, so the details get pretty gnarly. [godaemon](https://github.com/VividCortex/godaemon) has a small implementation with good discussion and links to more good discussion, and there's also the more popular and more traditionally implemented [go-daemon](https://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon).

The `ioctl` errors you are getting almost certainly come from the use of [`Setctty`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2647).

`Sys: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
            Foreground: false,
            Setsid:     true,
        },`

should get you semantics like `os/exec`'s `Start`, where the child process is not immediately reparented, but will safely be hoisted if/when the parent dies.

The `operation not permitted` you're seeing is, I think, about the pipes in `/tmp/`, from running under strace:

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/stdin", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3
epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)            = 4
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=471047936, u64=140179613654784}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 3, 0xc420039c24) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/stdout", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 5
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 5, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=471047936, u64=140179613654784}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 5, 0xc420039c24) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/stderr", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 6
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=471047936, u64=140179613654784}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 6, 0xc420039c24) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)`